# How to show/hide PhotoSwipe toolbars

Tags: jquery, plugins, toolbar, photoswipe

I am building a project based on Photoswipe.

Is there a way of creating an external call to show or hide the toolbars on demand? (i.e. if an external event user defined even occurs)

Is there an sort of API for Photoswipe?

Answer (score -1):

It's not documented but yes you can access internal methods of the PhotoSwipe UI.

Assume `gallery` is your main object

```
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
```

To hide UI

```
gallery.ui.hideControls();
```

To show UI

```
galleru.ui.showControls();
```